# Calling member function in transform()

Tags: c++, vector, transform, pointer-to-member

So I've been trying to use the transform function to create a vector from 2 existing ones. I succesfully managed to do it without classes but now I want to use classes and I get errors. The code bellow is only a small, relevant part of my project so it might seem silly but the whole thing actually makes sense in the end.

Here is part of my header file :

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Example
{
public:
    double multiply(double x, double y);
    void generate_amplitude(std::vector<double>& ampVec);
};
```

And some content of my .cpp file :

```
#include "example.h"

double Example::multiply(double x, double y)
{
    return x*y;
}

void Example::generate_amplitude(std::vector<double>& ampVec)
{
    double const a = 3.14;
    int const lenVectors = 10;

    std::vector<double> timeVec = {0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}
    std::vector<double> ampVec(lenVectors);
    std::vector<double> aVec(lenVectors, a);

    // Fill ampVec with timeVec[i]*aVec[i] for i in range[0:lenVectors[
    transform(timeVec.begin(), timeVec.end(), aVec.begin(), ampVec.begin(), multipy);
}
```

So when I try to compile, I get :

`error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '__binary_op (...)', e.g. '(... ->* __binary_op) (...)'`

I did search and read for hours about pointer-to-member functions, tried a few different ways like :

```
double (Example::*pmf)(double, double);
pmf = &Example::multiply;
transform(timeVec.begin(), timeVec.end(), aVec.begin(), ampVec.begin(), this->*pmf);
```

but I'm still new to this and couldn't find a way to make it work. This particular example returned that kind of message :

```
error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, double (Example::)(double, double))'
note: candidate: 'template<class _IIter, class _OIter, class _UnaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation)'
note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 5 provided
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed
note: candidate: 'template<class _IIter1, class _IIter2, class _OIter, class _BinaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation)'
note:   member function type 'double (Example::)(double, double)' is not a valid template argument
```

Help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to approach this problem would be with the use of lambdas:

```
transform(
    timeVec.begin(), timeVec.end(),
    aVec.begin(),
    ampVec.begin(),
    [this](double a, double b) { return multiply(a, b); }
);
```

You can't use a pointer-to-member-function here because you need the `this` pointer upon which to invoke the pointer-to-member-function, and `std::transform()` has no mechanism to supply this information.  Capturing `this` with the lambda solves that problem by making `this` part of the state of the functor.

You could do something similar in C++03 by writing a custom functor:

```
class ExampleMultiply {
public:
    explicit ExampleMultiply(Example &p) : example(p) {}

    double operator()(double a, double b) const {
        return example.multiply(a, b);
    }

private:
    Example &example;
};
```

Then invoking `std::transform()` with this functor:

```
transform(
    timeVec.begin(), timeVec.end(),
    aVec.begin(),
    ampVec.begin(),
    ExampleMultiply(*this)
);
```

Under the hood, this is basically what the compiler generates to implement the lambda expression.

Comment: You could use std::bind instead of the explicit lambda: std::bind(&Example::multiply, this, std::placeholder::_1, std::placeholder::_2)

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Indeed. Personally I prefer lambdas to `std::bind()` (I find it a bit redundant with lambdas, and the placeholders are a bit verbose for my taste) but it would definitely work. There's no shortage of ways to accomplish the same thing in C++, that's for sure.

Comment: I did use the lambdas solution and it works like a charm.
However after some testing I found that using a for loop to fill my ampVec was on average faster than using the transform function... Any idea why ? I had chosen this way precisely because I thought that an existing, dedicated function would be faster.

Comment: @Zeloon You might want to open a new question for that so we can see the code you're using for both your loop and the `transform` approach. We'd also need to see exactly how you're benchmarking. C++ is tricky to benchmark because the compiler is wicked smart and might actually remove code from the benchmark that it wouldn't remove when the code is used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem would be to make your multiply function static as it does not need to access `this`:

```
class Example
{
public:
    static double multiply(double x, double y);
    void generate_amplitude(std::vector<double>& ampVec);
};
```

Then you could pass your static function as so:

```
  transform(timeVec.begin(),timeVec.end(),
        aVec.begin(),
        ampVec.end(),
        Example::multiply);
```

Furthermore, I'd like to add that you shouldn't define your multiply function. Here is an example using [std::multiples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies):

```
transform(timeVec.begin(),timeVec.end(),
        aVec.begin(),
        ampVec.end(),
        std::multiplies<double>());
```